# Date format differs on iPhone

Tags: google-forms

I have created a (google) registration form online.  I set the date format to dd/mm/yyyy but when others access the form on their mobile, the format changes to mm/dd/yyyy

I would like the format to remain dd/mm/yyyy whatever device is used to access it.  This is a new development, had been working fine in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Google Forms use an input tag of date type for date questions. That means that input date format depends on the user web browser.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that if you are logged in to a Google account then the form will show the date format in the format of your account settings. I am in the UK and when I look at my forms while logged in I see DD/MM/YYYY.

However, if another user looks at the form who is not logged in to a Google account it seems to ALWAYS show MM/DD/YYYY.

So if I look at the form here in the UK on another device (device set to UK region) it still shows the american date format.

I don't think there is any fix. I have raised it on the Google issue tracker but I'm not holding my breath...

For me this means I can't really use the date field on a form as my users are English and half the time they enter the wrong dates as they expect DD/MM/YYYY, they don't see the american format on the form and enter dates wrong. I changed to use 3 dropdowns for Day/Month/Year and convert back to a date on the back end. It's rubbish but at least more dates are correct than before!